# Intel(HD) Graphics error installing drivers

Tags: drivers, system-installation, intel-graphics

I have a problem when i want to install Intel(HD) Graphisc driver.I use Intel HD Graphics installer for Linux and after 1 minute of installing come this error :

```
W:GPG error: https://download.01.org trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A902DDA375E52366, W:Failed to fetch http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/dists/precise/steam/i18n/Translation-en  Error reading from server. Remote end closed connection [IP: 80.157.170.56 80]
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have a Intel HD Graphics 4000

Comment: Do you have a problem with the default drivers from the `xserver-xorg-video-intel` package? I also have Intel HD 4000 and everything worked fine for me since install.

Comment: i don't know...i jut want to install the drivers but i can't...at the specification of my laptop at the Graphics it's this :  Intel® Ivybridge Mobile   not IntelHD Graphics 4000...

Comment: Are you currently installing Ubuntu, or have you already installed it? Are you having display problems?

Comment: I don't have display problems,but when i open a game the quality it's very bad and when i open photoshop it's pup-up a window with this message : Photoshop detected graphics hardware that it's not officially supported.If you experience problems,please uncheck the Graphics Processor checkbox in the Performance panel of the Preferences dialog.

Comment: from yesterday i installed the Ubuntu

Comment: Are you referring to performance problems in Windows or Ubuntu? If in Ubuntu, are you running Photoshop on Wine? I feel I should not that the "official" drivers from Intel are unlikely to improve performance significantly inside Ubuntu. They are open source, and thus the drivers already included in the Ubuntu installer are merely slightly older versions of the "official" drivers.

Answer (score 0):

You have started the Intel driver package update, but did not read the full set of instructions!

On the 01.org website where you found the link for the PPA, there are also specific [instructions](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2014/intelr-graphics-installer-1.0.6-linux) for Ubuntu to add the public key to your system so that you can verify downloads from that PPA.

You will need to open a terminal window <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>

Enter the commands

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg -O - | \
sudo apt-key add -

wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg-2 -O - | \
sudo apt-key add -
```

You can now complete the process of installing the Intel drivers.